# Apache NetBeans IDE 15 doesn't display special characters on console

Tags: netbeans

With NetBeans 15 I can write characters like 'à' and 'è' in the editor but if I try to print them in the console they are not displayed and this also happens if I enter the ASCII code of the characters. If I compile and run the program manually everything is fine.

Comment: Have you researched [similar-sounding questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans+display+characters+in+console+site:stackoverflow.com)? What were the results of your research? Can you share that with us? It's possible that one or more of the answers to those questions may help you.

Comment: Otherwise, how can we recreate this issue? In my NetBeans 15, and assuming Java, I run `System.out.println("à and è");` - and in the console I see `à and è` as expected. I did not make any configuration changes for this.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information: your operating system, your language (Java?), your language version, your code showing the data to be written to the console (in text form, not a screen shot), a screen shot of what you see in the NetBeans output window, and a screen shot showing the alternative console output where your code works. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to improve your question, because as it stands it is lacking in specifics, and is liable to be closed.

Comment: I'm using Java language on NetBeans IDE 15 (portable) with JDK 18. The operating system is Windows 11 (but it's the same on Windows 10).

Comment: In the projec properties the encoding is set to UTF-8

Comment: System.out.charset() returns windows-1252

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
the problem rises on one of the changes implemented in Java 18 that is [JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400). In it is stated: "Standardize on UTF-8 throughout the standard Java APIs, except for console I/O".

I have resolved adding (only for JDK 18)
`if(!"UTF-8".equals(System.out.charset().displayName())){ System.setOut(new PrintStream( new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); }`